# Difference between Publishing site and Team site while loading SP.JS

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, publishing-site, team-sites

I would like to know what is the difference when loading `SP.JS` file in Publishing site and Team Site.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.runtime.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomJSFunction, "SP.js");
```

The above code works for Publishing Site but not for team site.

Issue is the below line of code doesnt go to CustomJSFunction in team site.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomJSFunction, "SP.js");
```

But if its Publishing Site, the custom method gets executed.

> **Note**: If publishing features at site level and site collection level are enabled for Team site, then the code works fine and
>   CustomJSFunction is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) over [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) since it supports on demand scripts. Many SharePoint JavaScript libraries including `sp.js` are registered on demand using [ScriptLink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.aspx).

**About ScriptLink**

[ScriptLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.aspx) is a SharePoint server control for registering JavaScript files.

[ScriptLink.OnDemand property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.ondemand.aspx) determines whether the script should be loaded on demand like in case of `Team` site:

```
RegisterSod("sp.js", "https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/14927/_layouts/15/16.0.3912.1229/sp.js");
```

or loaded explicitly like in case of `Publishing` site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/14927/_layouts/15/16.0.3912.1229/sp.js"></script>
```

**Solution**

In case of `Team` site:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunc, "SP.js");
```

`myfunc` **will not be invoked** since [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) **does not support load on demand scripts**

So, the solution would be to utilize [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx), in that case the following code will be triggered in Team and Publishing sites:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', 
 function (){
     //your code goes here...
 });
```